# UNITY - How to make unity wait until i press i key

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making my very first game in unity. In this game my player is a ball which touches some question marks. When a question mark is triggered it has to display a question and the answers. Till here every thing is fine. Now i need to press a or b according to the question. If the answer is right it will add points. But here is the problem. Unity doesn't wait for me to press the keys. Unity passes through the code before i press the buttons and the game crashes.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("QuestionCube1"))
    {
        Question.text = "Which Number is bigger?";
        Answer.text = "A.5 B.10";
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            gameController.minusQuestion‌​Score();
        }
        else if (Input.GeyKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            gameController.addQuestionSc‌​ore();
        }
        Question.text = "";
        Answer.text = "";
    }
} 
//Sorry if the code is kinda all over the place I dont know how to pass the code here exactly. The gameController and the UI texts are declared and working
```

Comment: Make sure you post minimal code of your problem, so the problem can be more easy understood and identified.

Comment: You could edit the original post when posting code, in the comment section it gets unreadable. Non-the less, what is the reason for resetting the Question.text and Answer.text after the input? (And to answer your original question, it is not a good practice at all to "Wait" for the input). Firstly, maybe it is not necessary to reset the text, or there is very specific reason to do so?

Comment: The reason to reset them is to not have texts in my face while moving around. Well if the idea is not fine can u give me an example which does what i want? To answer the question via the keyboard. I must finish this until Saturday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay let's shift away from the comment section and let's try to improvise, on my current understandings of your problem.

First thing you must consider is the following.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
```

Triggers **ONLY** once, when the other collider enters. The solution?
Use OnTriggerStay.

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider collider)
```

This will always check for the input when the objects are colliding.

The next thing to consider is the reset of the text. As far as I understand you should remove it when they are not colliding anymore, so you could have additional method. OnTriggerExit, which will run additional code when they are not colliding anymore.

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("QuestionCube1"))
    {
        Question.text = "";
        Answer.text="";
    }
}
```

So overall

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) 
{ 
    if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("QuestionCube1")) 
    { 
        Question.text = "Which Number is bigger?"; 
        Answer.text = "A.5 B.10"; 

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            gameController.minusQuestion‌​Score();
        }
        else if(Input.GeyKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            gameController.addQuestionSc‌​ore();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Coroutine to wait for the input after it is triggered.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{

    if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("QuestionCube1"))
    {
        Question.text = "Which Number is bigger?";
        Answer.text = "A.5 B.10";
        StartCoroutine(WaitForAnswer());
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitForAnswer()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            gameController.minusQuestion‌​Score();
            break;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            gameController.addQuestionSc‌​ore();
            break;
        }
        yield return null;
    }

    Question.text = "";
    Answer.text = "";
    yield return null;
}
```